# Unique ROR User ID erb expression recognized in Jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

How do I pass a unique user id "erb expression" into a jquery function.

I.E

This

```
<div id="expand_<%= user.id %>"><%= image_tag user.avatar.url(:medium), :class => "expand round fluid" %></div>
    <div id="collapse_<%= user.id %>" class="collapse"><%= user.bio %></div>
```

into this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // Hide the "view" div.
      $('div.collapse').hide();
      // Watch for clicks on the "slide" link.
      $('div#expand_' + user.id).click(function() {
      // When clicked, toggle the "view" div.
      $('div#collapse_' + user.id).slideToggle(100);
      return false;
    });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't "pass it in". The value is there on the page within an HTML attribute. You just need to extract that value using Javascript.

But, more importantly, you don't even need to extract that value. All you're trying to do is "**slideToggle the div immediately after any div, with an id beginning with 'expand_', when that div is clicked**". Which, when translated into jQuery, is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       // Hide the "view" div.
       $('div.collapse').hide();
       // Watch for clicks on the "slide" link.
       $('div[id^=expand_').click(function() {
          // When clicked, toggle the "view" div.
          $(this).next('.collapse').slideToggle(100);
          return false;
       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yep put this in and it worked <code>    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
           // Hide the "view" div.
           $('div#collapse').hide();
           // Watch for clicks on the "slide" link.
           $('div#expand').click(function() {
              // When clicked, toggle the "view" div.
              $(this).next('#collapse').slideToggle(100);
              return false;
           });
        });
        </script></code>